# How to create date from a specified format in JavaScript similar to DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: javascript, php, date

I expect to get a date from my database in `Ymd` format.
This gives me values like `20200202`. This is fine for php applications but I'm using JavaScript for the frontend.

In php, we could do something like

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20200202');
```

meaning I get a date object as long as the formats match.

Is there a way for JavaScript to do this?

Comment: Just wondering, if you're using js as a frontend, why not adjusting the date in PHP (Server side - logic) and provide the final value to the frontend?

Comment: There something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat but pay attention to browser compatibility (page bottom)

Comment: @OfirBaruch it's the ACF plugin from WordPress, it doesn't provide a way to apply filters before saving to the database. client's choice so I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure this date will always come in the format `yyyymmdd`, you can use RegEx to extract the date :

```js
function getDate(inputDate)
{
  // TODO : Check if the format is valid
  
  
  const pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
  
  const parts = inputDate.match(pattern);
  
  // months start with 0 in js, that's why you need to substract 1
  // -----------------------v----------v
  return new Date(parts[1], parts[2] - 1, parts[3]);
}

console.log(getDate("20200202").toString());
console.log(getDate("20200213").toString());
console.log(getDate("20201231").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if the format matches your requirements and then split the value you get from the database. Then you could either return a Boolean value false if not possible or a date.

```
const dbOutput = '20200202';

const createdDate = getDate(dbOutput);


function getDate(value) {
    if(value.length !== 8) {
        return false;
    }

    const year = +value.substring(0,4);
    const month = +value.substring(4,6);
    const day = +value.substring(6,8);

    try {
        return new Date(year, month-1, day);
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what values of *value* will the catch block execute?